# Class object doesn't inherit other class attribute

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance

have 3 classes: Patient, Patients and Hospital.

```
class Patient:

    def __init__(self, ID, name, age, sex, alergies):
        self.ID = ID
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.sex = sex
        self.alergies = alergies

    def Is_old(self):
        if self.age >= 60:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def Add_patient(self, P):
        pass

class Patients():

    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {}    # where key is a patient ID, value is an Patient object


class Hospital(Patients):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def Get_oldPatients(self):
        old_patients = []
        for key, value in self.dict.items():   # where an error appears
            if Patient.Is_old():
                old_patients.append(value)
        return old_patients
```

an error appears

```
AttributeError: 'Hospital' object has no attribute 'dict'
```

Hospital class inherit from Patients so should have the same attribs like Patients, any idea where is the problem?

Comment: I suggest not creating a class `Patients`. You have `Patient`class from where you create `Patient` objects. Keep them either in a dict or in a list, as a variable of that type named `patients`. Also using the word `dict` (or `list`) as a name or data member in Python, is a terrible idea as they correspond to Python data types. Also an Hospital has patients, so you can pass your patients dict to the Hospital `__init__` to store it as an attribute `self..patients` of Hospital instance. I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: I meant Hospital *is not* a Patients object, but  can hold one patients object (dict or list object I suggest).